# How to get reference to jQuery selector's returning list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some jQuery function:

```
rfx.jQuery(function(){
    rfx.jQuery(".form-row.errors").blur(some_function(this))
});
```

But 'this' is HTMLDocument and not a list of selector return values. How can I get reference to list of elements?

Comment: I don't think you could have access of all the elements of the selectors *within* the `blur` function. You will have to call `jQuery(".form-row.errors")` again (or store this in a var previously, provided you won't change the DOM with your code).

Comment: Do you want to bind `some_function` to the blur event or does it *return* another function which you want to bind? Currently you are doing the latter.

Comment: Want to bind some_function to the blur event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of the selection itself ie `rfx.jQuery(".form-row.errors")` will be an array of the returned elements.

However in your blur event...

```
rfx.jQuery(".form-row.errors").blur(function(){
     //`this` is the element reference... 
});
```

See this [JS fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4X9AQ/) and tab between the input boxes.

You can't access the full selection from within the blur without either:

**a)** Selecting again within the `blur()` function...

```
rfx.jQuery(function(){
    rfx.jQuery(".form-row.errors").blur(function(){
         // `this` is the element which is blurring
         var formRowErrors = rfx.jQuery(".form-row.errors") //select again within the blur function
    });  
});
```

**b)** Using a closure, such as...

```
rfx.jQuery(function(){
    var formRowErrors = rfx.jQuery(".form-row.errors");
    rfx.jQuery(".form-row.errors").blur(function(){
         // `this` is the element which is blurring
         // formRowErrors is the jQuery selection of all form-row.errors
    });  
});
```

However, in this second method, the `var formRowErrors` will only contain the selection *at the time you bind* ie it is not "live"

Answer (score 1):

You have a context problem.

```
rfx.jQuery(".form-row.errors").blur(function(){
   some_function(this);
});
```

The anonymus function will have the result of `rfx.jQuery(".form-row.errors")` as `this` while if you do

```
rfx.jQuery(function(){
    rfx.jQuery(".form-row.errors").blur(some_function(this))
});
```

this would be the context in `rfx.jQuery`